# XPath query for nested href

Tags: xml, xpath

I need to parse this long number: `15-20001963-5-25580855-2-0-0-1-1-0-0-0-0-0-1-0-0-0-0` from the code below, and I don't know the exact XPATH query to use.

Can someone write an XPath to extract the value?

```
<div id="menu">
    <div id="splash">
        <div id="menuItem_1" class="ScreenTitle">Darts</div>
        <div id="menuItem_2" class="Title">In-Play</div>
        <div id="subMenu_2">
            <div id="menuItem_3" class="Level2">
                <a href="../coupon/?ptid=0&amp;key=15-20001963-5-25580855-2-0-0-1-1-0-0-0-0-0-1-0-0-0-0">
                    Adrian Lewis v Vincent van der Voort<br/>
                    <span class="Score">2-1</span>
                    <span class="Score">Set 4</span>
                </a>
            </div>
            <input id="IPCD" type="hidden" value="1~~False~True" />
            <input type="hidden" id="refresh" value="no">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

The XPath expression to get the `href` attiribute of the `<a>` element containing your number could be for example:

```
 id('menuItem_3')/a/@href
```

This will get you a string value:

> ../coupon/?ptid=0&key=15-20001963-5-25580855-2-0-0-1-1-0-0-0-0-0-1-0-0-0-0

which you then need to parse. The concrete implementation of how to obtain the number depends on what parsing engine and/or programming language you're using, but XPath won't help you here.

Comment: (Or, to be perfectly correct, it could help you here, but I would advise against using XPath to substring the `href` value. Use your programming language's features.)

Comment: When did XPath start supporting syntax like `id('menuItem_3')`? I assume this is equivalent to `//*[@id='menuItem_3']`

Comment: @Phil Right from the start. [It's in the XPath 1.0 spec.](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-id) And yes, it is the same thing, just shorter and defined to work with unique IDs.

Comment: Ah, I was about to say maybe I'm too old (assuming it was a new thing) but maybe I'm not old enough ;)

Comment: On XML documents the `id` function is only useful on documents that have a DTD that defines which attributes are actually ids, which rather limits its usefulness these days.

Answer (score 2):

The following XPath will select the value: `15-20001963-5-25580855-2-0-0-1-1-0-0-0-0-0-1-0-0-0-0` from the provided XML input using the [**`substring-after()` function**](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-substring-after) to select the substring after "key=" in the href value.

```
substring-after(//div[@id='menuItem_3']/a/@href,'key=')
```